# Async method problrm

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, asynchronous

I have an async method. Which idea is to `findById` an entity, make changes to this entity and then save it. When I call this method, the method throws execption that this entity is not found in the database. But it exists in the database.

```
@Async("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public void promoteTest(String groupId, String authHeader) {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    Group group =groupRepository.findById(groupId).orElseThrow(() -> new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "group - " + groupId + " not found."));
```

The problem is `groupRepository.findById` .

```
@Bean("threadPoolTaskExecutor")
public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
    return executor;
}
```

Comment: Well apparently it doesn't exists else the exception wouldn't be thrown. Make sure you are looking at the same database and that the data you need is actually commited.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is not the problem

Comment: It is. Else the data would be there. So it either isn't committed yet (so not visible) or you are checking a different database.